# azure media services - The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using the java SDK and followed the example on: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-java-how-to-use
However, using this example, for files larget than ~65MB I got the following error: 
`RequestBodyTooLarge`The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
Any idea? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the Media Services Java SDK has a limitation on the size of the file to upload when using the provided **createBlockBlob** method.

To workaround this, you can leverage the file upload through the [Azure Storage Java SDK](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java) if you need to upload files larger than 64MB. To do this, update the example as follows:

1) For example, if you are using Gradle build tool, add this line to the **build.gradle** file under the dependencies section: ([package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage))

```
dependencies { 
  // ...
  compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '4.0.0'
}
```

2) Add the following import directives to your code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;
```

3) Replace the following block of code of the **uploadFileAndCreateAsset** method

```
// Create the Blob Writer using the Locator
uploader = mediaService.createBlobWriter(uploadLocator);

File file = new File("BigBuckBunny.mp4"); 

// The local file that will be uploaded to your Media Services account
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

System.out.println("Uploading " + fileName);

// Upload the local file to the asset
uploader.createBlockBlob(fileName, input);
```

With the following block of code:

```
try {
    CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(URI.create(uploadLocator.getPath()));

    // The blob reference of the asset file
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("BigBuckBunny.mp4");

    // The local file that will be uploaded to your Media Services account
    File sourceFile = new File("BigBuckBunny.mp4");

    // Upload the local file to the asset
    blob.upload(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.length());

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Track the exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```