# azure media services，large size video upload and encode

Tags: azure-media-services

according to  [azure media services - The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958465/azure-media-services-the-request-body-is-too-large-and-exceeds-the-maximum-per#new-answer,upload) large size video works well, but after uploaded ,asset can not been encoded,anyone can  help me ?

my code like this:

```
@Override
    protected void createBlobWriter(LocatorInfo uploadLocator, String fileName, InputStream input)
            throws ServiceException {
        try {
            CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(URI.create(uploadLocator.getPath()));
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            blob.upload(input, input.available());
        }
        catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

do encode in https://portal.azure.cn,
and encode run error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsS9w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because the fileName had a character (in this case, "?") which is not supported. If you can update your code to only allow alphanumeric characters(to be safe), then encoding should work. See the Note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-upload-files for a list of unsupported characters.

Comment: Yes,the fileName contained a  ‘？’ character。 I have removed it.and it works。Thanks